# Redirect user to 3rd Party's "Desktop version" website in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

Is there a way to redirect user to a 3rd party's "Desktop Version" site?  Right now I have:

header("Location: https://othersite.com"); 
exit();

But the "othersite.com" detects the user and shows them their mobile site. I would like to show the "othersite.com" desktop version. How do I do this?

Comment: How does the "other site" differentiate its mobile and desktop versions? Using a subdomain? A request path? Responsive CSS? Something else? And what does it mean that it "detects the user"?

Comment: Try to send correct `User-Agent` in header() call

Comment: @BorLaze — `User-Agent` is a **request** header. It doesn't belong in an HTTP response.

Answer (score -2):

maybe the other site accept a mobile=no parameter ...

`header("Location: https://othersite.com/?mobile=no"); exit();`

Comment: I guess it technically _might_, but it probably doesn't. What makes you think this would work?